# Equations of lines tangent to $x^2+2x+2y^2−4y=5$ that are normal to $y=x+12$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation, tangent-line

I need to verify if what I am doing is correct here. This is my question:

> Write down the equations of tangent lines to the curve of the implicit function $x^2+2x+2y^2−4y=5$ that are normal to the line $y=x+12$.

I don't know why I am struggling with this so much. If the equation of the tangent line is normal to the line $y=x+12$, that would mean that the slope of the normal line is $m=-1$. In that case, if I implicitly differentiate, I get:

$$2x+2+4yy'-4y'=0$$

That would mean I have:

$$2x+2-4y+4=0$$

$$2x-4y+6=0$$

How do I find the points of tangency though? I feel like I am missing very stupid and obvious, but I am not sure.

Comment: Use your last equation to find $y$ in terms of $x$. Plug that into your original equation to find which values of $x$ correspond to points on the curve. Each of these points, along with the slope, will give you an equation for a tangent line.

Comment: I got it. Thanks. I knew it was something silly.